# How to handle color contrast accessibility issue on disabled button

Tags: css, accessibility, high-contrast

There's a button conditionally disabled, and the disabled button is greyed out.

The background color is  `#e0e0e0` and the text color is `#a6a6a6`, so the contrast ratio is 1.84 out of a required 4.5. I was wondering if there's any way to skip the color contrast check on the disabled button.

It already has the `aria-disabled` property now.

Comment: If you genuinely care about accessibility, the only way to skip it is to not skip it: change the color. Visual disabilities are not "normally sighted" vs. "blind", there's an entire spectrum of poor eyesight in between those two, and aria roles do nothing for almost all those folks. They still look at your content in the browser like anyone else, but they won't be able to tell that button is disabled because the two colors basically look the same to them.

Answer (score -1):

There are quite a few differing opinions about disabled buttons, but the general consensus is that you need a lot of extra code to make it accessible. Not only are the colour contrasts of standard disabled buttons not AA compliant, but the fact that the button becomes not intractable causes issues for keyboard users, as the focus will just skip straight past the button.

A better option would be to not use the `disabled` attribute, and instead give it a disabled class, as shown below. This ensures that the contrast is controlled by you and can be of a sufficient contrast ratio, whilst still maintaining the un-clickable functionality that you want, and avoiding frustration for keyboard-only users. You can then also apply some text to explain why the button isn't intractable.

```
.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: your-contrasting-colour-here;
}
```